# How to have bold text?

Tags: html, xcode, email, bold

I made an app for my self for work to mail my self a complete service order documentation but I want to have bold text before the + random.text! so it's easier to read.

Examples:
messageBody += "\nFöretag: " + kundForetag.text! = Företag: Google.se <-- How it looks now
messageBody += "\nFöretag: " + kundForetag.text! = **Företag:** Google.se  <-- I want it to look like this in the mail. Where "Företag:" is bold text

Can anyone help me out ?

```js
import MessageUI
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    // Bara light mode
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light 
        
    // Fixar så att textView ser ut som textField
        grindInformation.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        grindInformation.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        grindInformation.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        grindInformation.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    // Göm keyboard när manrör utanför text area
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

    // Göm keyboard när man trycker på retur
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return (true)
        }
    
// KUND INFORMATION
    @IBOutlet weak var kundForetag: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundOrgnr: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundMarkning: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundAdress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundStad: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundPostnummer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundKontakt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundTelefon: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var kundEpost: UITextField!
    
    
// GRIND INFORMATION
    @IBOutlet weak var grindTyp: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var grindTid: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var grindMil: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var grindInformation: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var grindCE: UITextField!
    
// SERVICETEKNIKER / SUBJECT
    @IBOutlet weak var teknikerSubject: UITextField!
    
// Skicka Iconen = Genererar mailet
    @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Modify following variables with your text / recipient
        let recipientEmail = "mail@randommail.com"
        let subject = "Ny serviceorder av: " + teknikerSubject.text!
    // KUND INFORMATION
        var messageBody = "- Företags Information -"
        messageBody += "\nFöretag: " + kundForetag.text!
        messageBody += "\nOrganisationsnummer: " + kundOrgnr.text!
        messageBody += "\nFakturamärkning: " + kundMarkning.text!
        messageBody += "\nAdress: " + kundAdress.text!
        messageBody += "\nStad: " + kundStad.text!
        messageBody += "\nPostnummer: " + kundPostnummer.text!
        messageBody += "\nKontakt: " + kundKontakt.text!
        messageBody += "\nTelefon: " + kundTelefon.text!
        messageBody += "\nE-post: " + kundEpost.text!
    // GRIND INFORMATION
        messageBody += "\n\n- Order Detaljer -"
        messageBody += "\nGrind: " + grindTyp.text! + " (CE)" + grindCE.text!
        messageBody += "\nMil: " + grindMil.text!
        messageBody += "\nTid: " + grindTid.text!
        messageBody += "\n\n"
        messageBody += "\n" + grindInformation.text!
        messageBody += "\n\n"
        
        
    // Show default mail composer
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients([recipientEmail])
            mail.setSubject(subject)
            mail.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)

            present(mail, animated: true)

    // Show third party email composer if default Mail app is not present
        } else if let emailUrl = createEmailUrl(to: recipientEmail, subject: subject, messageBody: messageBody) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(emailUrl)
        }
    }

// Om mail inte är installerat så väljer den någon av följande mail app. Om ingen av dessa finns så ber appen dig att installera Mail appen.
    private func createEmailUrl(to: String, subject: String, messageBody: String) -> URL? {
        let subjectEncoded = subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
        let messageBodyEncoded = messageBody.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

        let outlookUrl = URL(string: "ms-outlook://compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(messageBodyEncoded)")
        let gmailUrl = URL(string: "googlegmail://co?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(messageBodyEncoded)")
        let yahooMail = URL(string: "ymail://mail/compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(messageBodyEncoded)")
        let sparkUrl = URL(string: "readdle-spark://compose?recipient=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(messageBodyEncoded)")
        let defaultUrl = URL(string: "mailto:\(to)?subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(messageBodyEncoded)")

        if let outlookUrl = outlookUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(outlookUrl) {
        return outlookUrl
        } else if let gmailUrl = gmailUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(gmailUrl) {
        return gmailUrl
        } else if let yahooMail = yahooMail, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(yahooMail) {
            return yahooMail
        } else if let sparkUrl = sparkUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(sparkUrl) {
            return sparkUrl
        }

        return defaultUrl
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UILabel`. 
You can change the font in the controller something like this :

`yourVariable.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)`

You can configure size from 22 to any number as well.

Comment: But that won't make it bold inside the mail.

Comment: I got it working in the default Mail client but not in Outlook :/